# The (new) blog button disappears when logged in

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

There's a blog button with a "new" label that popped up on the SE bar at the top of each page when I logged out. When I log back in, it disappears. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is intentional. When you are logged in the topnav is pretty full, so we don't have room to mirror the blog indicator there.

It is still in the footer, as you can see.

Comment: Righto. I saw it down there, but was just making sure.